# is spring async pass object thread safe to previous update

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, asynchronous

we are using spring async framework, sample code as below, if Entity object is mutable and has been updated BEFORE the call to put, will JVM guarantee that put will see the change?

```
@Async("daoExecutor")
@Repository
public class GenericDaoImpl implements GenericDao {
    public CompletableFuture<Entity> put(Entity e) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

`@Async` is more or less implemented by wrapping the actual method invocation in a `Callable` and submitting that callable to a `ThreadPoolExecutor`. That submission is done through a `BlockingQueue`. The default `BlockingQueue` implementations provided by the JDK (which Spring uses) are all thread safe. Adding to the queue *happens-before* taking from the queue.

So any changes you make before calling `put` (and adding to the queue) will be visible in the `put` (which happens after taking from the queue).